# need some php and HTML code encryption?so that user can't see or edit the code

Tags: php, encryption

i have a framework, where i will setup it for free.But we make money only through maintenance.

So i don't want the customer to see the code and the encryption code should run from my server.So that he can't run the website anymore.

Comment: please explain yourself... obviously an end user could see the HTML...

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate HTML? Every man and his dog can write HTML. I think doing this is likely to deter people from using your framework

Comment: ya end user can , but the developer can not edit it.

Comment: So you want to create a framework that no developers can use?

Comment: oh... just don't give them access to the server. that's easy enough...

Comment: i won't host the entire code, i will host only the ecncryped key from my server.If he remove the link , then entire system should not work.

Comment: as i understood, this php code is on the client server and op wants to create some encryption system, which will use "secret" script on his own server. @Balaji, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Like fingerman said. You have to run the server yourself and give your customer accounts to log in.

Comment: i don't want to host the entire code , i just want give the framework just like nulled version